# Keeping two infinity stones close together

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe

It is too dangerous to have two infinity stones in the same world. This is why the Asgardians give the Reality Stone to the Collector at the end of Thor: The Dark World. [since there already was the tesseract (the Space Stone) in Asgard].

However, aren't there two infinity stones on Earth? Vision has the Mind Stone on his head and there is the Time Stone in the Eye of Agamotto in Kamar-Taj, as shown in Doctor Strange. So, isn't it dangerous **keeping two Infinity Stones so close together**?

Comment: Do the avengers exist in the Dr Strange movie timeline?

Comment: My guess is they simply don't know about the Eye of Agamotto, since the sorcerers are deliberately secretive (even acknowledging that they don't help the Avengers) and--if I'm remembering Age of Ultron correctly--Thor didn't even know how many Infinity Stones existed until his vision in that movie, much less where they all were. Unfortunately I don't recall any solid proof that they don't know about the Eye yet.

Comment: @DustinDavis They definitely are in the same timeline. Dr Strange has a line about how the Avengers deal with physical threats while sorcerers deal with more mystical threats (or something to that effect) as an explanation for not teaming up with them.

Comment: @lxrec ah, yes. I forgot about that part.

Comment: The post credit scene from Dr Strange showed Thor enlisting Strange's help.

Comment: My interpretation of the proximity issue is that it was related to making the Stones easier to locate. Not that there was a danger of the interacting. I'm on mobile and can't check the actual dialogue.

Comment: Ok. Even if the danger is locating, having two on Earth is still a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vision's (Mind) Infinity-stone came from [Loki's scepter](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Chitauri_Scepter) which came from the Chitauri, so it was well away from Earth, brought to Earth by someone with plans for all the mind-stones (Thanos).   It was only very recently on Earth.

The [Tesseract (Space-stone)](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Tesseract) was hidden on Earth, presumably by Odin, for safe keeping.  Taken back to Asgard when it was no longer safe on Earth.

It's worth pointing out that safekeeping can be done under heavy guard or it can be done by simply hiding something.   The Tesseract on Earth for centuries, and the stone in Guardians-1 ([Orb or Power-Stone](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/The_Orb)) weren't guarded well at all, just hidden.

The Origin of the Eye-of-Agamotto in the cinematic universe wasn't made clear but presumably the first sorcerer supreme, Agamotto, who is mentioned in the movie, knew what it was.

So there were likely 2 stones on Earth for some time, Tesseract and Agamotto, which fits your question, one hidden, one protected in a magical sanctum.    What's not clear is whether either keeper/protector of each of those stone knew of the other.   It's not something anyone is likely to advertise, so Odin and Agamotto may well not have known of each other's stones.

When Shield took Loki's scepter and stored it in the vault, it's unclear if Thor knew it was the mind-stone at the time.  Dr. Selvig might have suspected, but it's unclear how much he knew about infinity stones.   If it was known that the scepter held a stone after Avengers-1, and it's not clear that it was known, but if it was known, the thinking at the time could well have been - one stone under Shield protection, one back to Odin's protection.

Thor had a vision of the stones in the sacred water in Avengers-II, but precisely how much he knows about their location isn't clear, so it's still not clear if anyone other than the sorcerers know the location of the time-stone.

The risk with Odin's thrown room is that, even under guard, it's fairly common knowledge that it was full of juicy loot.   The feeling might have been that such a high profile vault shouldn't contain two stones, especially since one is fairly well known to be there after the events in Avengers-1.   If the stones are better hidden, Agamotto for example, that issue might not come up.

Comment: Did Odin keep the tesseract on Earth for safekeeping Or did he lose it on Earth?

Comment: @ironman I'd assumed it was safekeeping.   The old man who guarded it seemed to know something of it's danger, but Odin losing it or it being lost on Earth some other way is possible too.   If anyone can clarify that, I welcome the correction.

Comment: s/thrown/throne/ (too short of an edit for the website to allow me to propose through the website's official editing system)